# Dynamically adding <input> to form using checkboxes using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, paypal

I have a website that people can book courses and workshops on. They can pay by paypal but currently when they go to check out it asks for all their bookings if they have more than one to be paid.

This is done using a simple `while` loop that displays all the bookings for the specified customer ID.

However, depending on the starting date of the course etc, not all of them have to be paid immediately and so I'd like to give customers the option of choosing which bookings they want to pay for.

In doing this I want to know if there is a way to dynamically add fields to a form (before it goes to paypal) using checkboxes given on the page to decide which bookings the customer wishes to pay for.

An example is at [www.peaknature.co.uk/payment-example.php](http://www.peaknature.co.uk/payment-example.php)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the .append() function of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/append/

And here's an example of how to use it: http://papermashup.com/dynamically-add-form-inputs-and-submit-using-jquery/

Comment: Thank you. I had look at this but become confused as to how to include information from more than one row in the resultant form. Am I right in thinking you just intersperse the javascript with `<?php ?>` tags?